# How to obtain a line break in an amsthm definition containing a citation?

Tags: citing, line-breaking, margins, theorems, amsthm

Consider following MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{fruit}{Definition of a kind of fruit}

\begin{document}

Let's define some fruits. But first some text to reach till the right margin and even a little further.

\begin{fruit}[{Banana, as found in the book \cite[chapter 31]{ref1}}]
A banana is a yellow fruit that grows on a tree.
\end{fruit}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
  \bibitem{ref1}  O. Outan. The big book of bananas. Fruit Editions Ltd.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

which yields

[image]

As you see, the definition name

```
[{Banana, as found in the book \cite[chapter 31]{ref1}}]
```

contains a citation and therefore, the entire name has been placed between `{}` in order to avoid an error. It turns out that an overhang is obtained. Is there a straightforward way to obtain a line break here?

**Update**

- I would like the first line of the theorem to be justified text.
- In this case, would it possible to split inside the citation?

  ................................... [1,

  chapter 31]. A banana is

Comment: amsmath isn't involved here

Answer (score 3):

`amsmath` isn't involved in theorem definitions but the AMS package `amsthm` does provided an extended theorem declaration that allows line breaking here.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{fruit}{Definition of a kind of fruit}

\begin{document}

Let's define some fruits. But first some text to reach till the right margin and even a little further.

\begin{fruit}[{Banana, as found in the book\\ \cite[chapter 31]{ref1}}]
A banana is a yellow fruit that grows on a tree.
\end{fruit}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
  \bibitem{ref1}  O. Outan. The big book of bananas. Fruit Editions Ltd.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: OK. See updated question for more details.

Comment: In this case, the title is not bold anymore, and the title is no longer justified text.