# How to force a linebreak in a theorem title?

Tags: citing, line-breaking, theorems

(This is a follow-up question to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/602013/how-to-obtain-a-line-break-in-an-amsthm-definition-containing-a-citation).)

Consider following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{fruit}{Definition of a kind of fruit}

\begin{document}

Let's define some fruits. But first some text to reach till the right margin and even a little further.

\begin{fruit}[Banana, as found in the book \\ {\cite[chapter 31]{ref1}}]
A banana is a yellow fruit that grows on a tree.
\end{fruit}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
  \bibitem{ref1}  O. Outan. The big book of bananas. Fruit Editions Ltd.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Why is there no linebreak in the title?

Comment: Theorems are basically lists, so the theorem title is put into a `\item[...]`, which in turn is typeset in a `\hbox`, where ``\\`` has no effect. BTW, bananas do not grow on *trees* `;-)`.

Comment: Maybe because the so-called ‘banana tree’ is not really a tree? ;o)